# How to get TF-IDF while using HashingVectorizer in large text data

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I am using scikit sklearn in python. It will report memory error when I use all text data in `countvectorizer` or `HashingVectorizer`.So I'm trying to get `TF-IDF` using `HashingVectorizer` by online learning in large text data.The code is that:

```
chunk_size = 1000
vectorizer = HashingVectorizer()
transformer = TfidfTransformer()

train_data_text = []
tfidf = None
for i in range(0,df.shape[0]):
    file_word = convert_doc_to_wordlist(str(df.iloc[i,1]), cut_all=False)
    sentencestr = " ".join(word for word in file_word)
    train_data_text.append(sentencestr)

    if (i+1)%chunk_size == 0:
        Wordfrequency = vectorizer.transform(train_data_text)
        tfidfchunk = transformer.fit_transform(Wordfrequency)
        if tfidf == None:
            tfidf = tfidfchunk
        else:
            tfidf = np.vstack((tfidf, tfidfchunk))
        train_data_text =[]

        sys.stdout.flush()
        sys.stdout.write("%.3f" %(float(i)/float(df.shape[0])))
        sys.stdout.write( '  ')
```

I see that `HashingVectorizer` has a method [partial_fit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer.partial_fit) . And I also see [the example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_out_of_core_classification.html) how learn from data that doesn’t fit into main memory by `HashingVectorizer` . But I didn't see the `partial_fit` method of  instead the `partial_fit` method of some classifiers.

1. How do I use the `partial_fit` method of `HashingVectorizer` or just
   as my code use `transform`?
2. When should I calculate the `TF-IDF` from `HashingVectorizer`, is
   carried out with `HashingVectorizer` or after the completion of
   `HashingVectorizer`?
3. Whether online learning can be used to calculate `TF-IDF`?How to do
   it?